# Is there a good documentation or your own instructions on how to install Berkeley DB XML Python API on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, berkeley-db, berkeley-db-xml

I am supposed to install Berkeley DB and Berkeley DB XML for the first time and have specifically struggled out of the `IOError: No such file or directory db\include\db.h` problem. But after that I encountered another problem: `Namerror: name 'db_ver_list' is not defined`. Is there any documentation which can make me install these database API for Python on Windows? Or you could give me instructions or steps to do that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that for Python 2.7 on Windows your only option is to build the modules from the [sources](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html) following the [Oracle provided instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html) (according to these [instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html) the [sources](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/ref_xml/xml_win/intro.html) contain specific instructions for building the Python bindings in the `dbxml-2.5.16\dbxml\src\python` sub-directory).

You'll need to install the free Visual C++ 2008 Express compiler, which can be installed from the offline installation [Visual Studio 2008 Express iso](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=20682), to be able to perform the compilation of the Berkeley DB/DBXML [sources](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17276_01/html/ref_xml/xml_win/intro.html).